# Explain the distribution of these random variables?

Tags: r, exponential-distribution

Suppose I have 3 eggs, with independent hatching times (in minutes) following an $\text{Exp}(0.05)$ distribution, and A is defined as the earliest hatching time. 
 If I were to plot A, how would I explain its distribution? 
 From running a simulation on R, I can see that the histogram of A follows an exponential distribution but I'm not sure why?

Answer (score 4):

This is because the minimum of a collection of exponentially distributed random variables is also exponentially distributed. For a proof, see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution#Distribution_of_the_minimum_of_exponential_random_variables)